# font-size animation not working correctly on safari

Tags: css, animation, safari

I have a CSS animation that works fine on Firefox and Chrome but jitter on Safari.

It is on this page:
http://www.warhaftig.com/access-marketing.html

CSS:

```
    /* ------------- msg -------*/
@-webkit-keyframes animate-selection {
    from {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    }

    to {
    font-size: 2.9em;
    color: #fff;
    }
}


@keyframes animate-selection {
    from {
    font-size: 2.7em;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    }

    to {
    font-size: 2.9em;
    color: #fff;
    }
}

.msg-marketing li.selected-msg a {
    font-family: 'Neue Haas Unica W01 Medium It', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.9em;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 34px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation: animate-selection 600ms ease-out; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-name: animate-selection;
    animation-duration: 600ms;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

I am adding a `.selected-msg` class to style the li text when it it selected.

Answer (score 2):

Look below what we can read about using `font-size` in animation on the [CSS Triggers page](https://csstriggers.com/font-size).

> Changing `font-size` alters the geometry of the element. That means that it may affect the position or size of other elements on the page, both of which require the browser to perform layout operations.
>
> Once those layout operations have completed any damaged pixels will need to be painted and the page must then be composited together.

In clear, for better performances, avoid to do animation on `font-size` property.

In your case, you can use `transform` property and the `scale()` function to get a smoother result, because :

> Changing `transform` does not trigger any geometry changes or painting, which is very good. This means that the operation can likely be carried out by the compositor thread with the help of the GPU.

You can see a live example with your CSS on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/julienvanderkluft/v4nocgtn/) ! Just click on `Run` to see the effect running.

Comment: Just wanted to add my two pence to this answer. Scale does work so much better, but make sure you scale DOWN from your max value, not the other way around. That is, if you want to scale from 20px to 40px, make your font-size 40px and scale by 0.5 - if you make your font-size 20px and scale by 2 then it will end up blurred. Scale's also not perfect, as it will munge the rendering a little at certain sizes; if you're doing incredibly slow animations you will notice that it can look a bit odd.

Comment: Great! So smooth result!